# BASH : Feeding file to while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have next code with while loop in my sctipt :

```
TMP_FILE=`mktemp`
some_script.sh | grep aa > $TMP_FILE 
while read i
   do
      echo $i
      number=`ssh somehost cat somefile | grep 11 `  
      echo $number
   done < $TMP_FILE
```

Contents of TMP_FILE looks like :

```
hostname1 AB_CDEF_JH10
hostname2 BC_DEF_JK19
...
```

In this case, script works correctly only  one loop pass, picking up first line from TMP_FILE. After that , script exit. Is there any idea why it do not want to process other lines except firs one ?

Comment: Useless use of cat: `ssh -n somehost grep 11 somefile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the `-n` option to `ssh` to prevent it from reading from stdin.

By default, `ssh` reads from stdin (which is your file, in this case) and forwards it to the stdin of the command running on the remote host. As a result, your whole file gets consumed by `ssh` and the loop only executes once!

Comment: In this case, why use a `$TMP_FILE` at all? Just pipe it into the `while` loop.